# Can't create user using UserManager with the duplicate e-mail

Tags: c#, webapi

Its not a duplicate. My code is failing to create an account object (user) with the same e-mail address (it asserts with the failure):

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(account);
                    Debug.Assert(result != null && IdentityResult.Success.Succeeded == result.Succeeded);
```

I have found solution only for MVC5 project but I have a legacy project that does not have the `IdentityConfig.cs` file.

I also tried this solution but without any success:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;

            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Is there a solution for the ASP.NET Core Web API template ?

Comment: look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0